# Inverse Laplace transform in a signal that is a sum of exponentials - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, exponential

I want to analyze a discrete signal in time, that is sum of exponentials distributed around two distinct values (T1, T2). My goal is to calculate these two different distributions, T1, T2, weights and standard deviations.

I have found two MATLAB scripts doing this using Inverse Laplace transform:

http://www.wolfson.cam.ac.uk/~ssr24/invlap.html

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6523-rilt/content/rilt.m

I am trying to check the accuracy of the algorithm using as an input a sum of two exponentials with different time constants.

S(t)=a1*exp(-t/T1)+a2*exp(-t/T2)

Ideally the algorithm should return two peaks at T1 and T2 and weights a1 a2, but It returns two Gaussians with quite big dispersion around the T1 and T2 (see ex 2 on the second link).

Can you recommend any solution in order to get more specific results? even with another method (not inverse Laplace transform).

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Inverse laplace transform should be going from frequency (s-domain) back to time domain, but you seem to be starting with time. Do you have some code and example of what you have tried?

Comment: I do not have found documentation for the algorithm of the script. However, there is a very good example in this link:
http://www.wolfson.cam.ac.uk/~ssr24/invlap.html

*just copy-paste the matlab command